# jQuery Clipboard Copy

Tags: jquery, copy, clipboard

I need Clipboard Copy functionality, even i m taking help from  http://plugins.jquery.com/project/copy  link but it is not working fine.

```
<li>
     <label class="FieldName">
       Url:
     </label>
     <a id="url" href="<%=Model.FinalPacketUrl %>" target="_blank">
        <%=Model.FinalUrl %></a> </li>
 <li>
     <label class="FieldName">
      Password:
     </label>
 <span id="pwd">
    <%=Model.FinalPassword %></span> </li>
```

This is my Jquery code.This is just only copy text not text value

```
  function CopyToClipboard() {
    var text = $("#url").attr("href") + "\n" + $("#pwd").html();
           $.copy(text);
        }
```

Please help me to fix this problem

Comment: That id doesn't seem to reference any of the DOM elements you pasted...which of those elements' text are you trying to copy?

Comment: i read a article that we need some flash file creation to run it on other browser.

Comment: I just did a test in chrome and found that the plugin only works with the ersion of jquery supplied, what version are you using.

Comment: i am jusing jquery 1.3.2, download it from http://plugins.jquery.com/project/copy

Comment: regards the flash there is one in the downoaded file so make sure the url on line 79 of the unminified script is correct. the current minified script needs the flash file on the same url as the html page not the script.

Comment: jquery 1.3.2 doesn't work with that script you need to use 1.2.5 included in the zip download

Comment: this is only working with IE not in all browser.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try the following plugin:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/clipboard

Comment: Hello, this link redirects to jquery's home page. Is this plugin not available anymore?

Comment: @user2745266 seems that it's not available anymore

Comment: Okay. Could you please suggest an alternative?