# Copy value from input to clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is there any chance to copy the value of my inputbox to the clipboard with javascript?

```
<input id="iban_iban" name="iban" type="text" size="39" maxlength="47" />
```

I found a lot of stuff to copy content from a textarea but I did not found any way to copy it from an inputbox.

Thank you very much

Comment: What did you find to copy content from a textarea? The method shouldn't be much different for an input

Comment: Review this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069663/jquery-clipboard-copy